# Recomposition not happening using data class copy in mutable state for second time

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to recompose by copying the ui state with a different value but recomposition is not happening. From the code below check I am trying to set an error state if photo count is max limit, recomposition does not happen when validate count is executed the second time.

```
data class UiState( 
val isLoading: Boolean = false,
val error: String = "",
val isSuccess: Boolean = false
)

@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel() : ViewModel{

  var state by mutableStateOf(UiState())

  fun validateCount(size: Int): Boolean {
    state = state.copy(error = if (size > 5) "Max limit" else "")
  }

}

@Composable
fun MyScreen(viewModel: MyViewModel = hiltViewModel()){

   val state = viewModel.state

   val multiplePhotoPickerLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.PickMultipleVisualMedia(),
        onResult = { uris ->
            if (viewModel.validateCount(uris.size))
                selectedImageUris = uris
        }
    )

  if (state.error.isNotEmpty()) ErrorView(error = state.error)

  .
  .
  .
}
```

Comment: `validateCount` returns Unit, so this will cause an error: `if (viewModel.validateCount(uris.size))`.

Comment: My bad, please ignore that it is returning boolean only in the current code. I am more concerned about the recomposition issue